# Apple Sign in Web implementation not getting user information

Tags: php, apple-sign-in

I am implementing Apple Sign in on my webpage. I manage to log in as a user and get redirected to another page where I receive this information:

Access Token Response

```
   stdClass Object
      (
        [access_token] => <redacted>
        [token_type] => Bearer
        [expires_in] => 3600
        [refresh_token] => <redacted>
        [id_token] => <redacted>
      )
```

From the id_token I can retreive this:

Parsed ID Token

```
stdClass Object
  (
    [iss] => https://appleid.apple.com
    [aud] => com.mywebsite.webapp
    [exp] => 1604672418
    [iat] => 1604586018
    [sub] => 000263.03f6a4fd925e446bbfa1dcb4c6a80e10.0113
    [at_hash] => 5futRg0Tq28zxt5Z7gt8lQ
    [email] => myname@gmail.com
    [email_verified] => true
    [auth_time] => 1604586017
    [nonce_supported] => 1
)
```

But I need to have the user's first name and last name as well which is not in the response. I know Apple sends it only the first time the user authorizes the app, and they may have sent it, but not anymore. I am always deleting the app from my apple account before testing the sign in, but in vain.

CODE:

```
$client_id = 'com.mywebsite.webapp';
$client_secret = 'sfsf0sfsgsdfg';
$redirect_uri = 'https://mywebsite.com/AppleLogin/appleresponse.php';

if(isset($_POST['code'])) {

  echo "POSTstate: " . $_POST["state"] . "<br>";

      $response = http('https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token', [
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'code' => $_POST['code'],
        'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
        'client_id' => $client_id,
        'client_secret' => $client_secret,
      ]);

      if(!isset($response->access_token)) {
        echo '<p>Error getting an access token:</p>';
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($response); echo '</pre>';
        echo '<p><a href="/">Start Over</a></p>';
        die();
      }

      echo '<h3>Access Token Response</h3>';
      echo '<pre>'; print_r($response); echo '</pre>';
    
    
      $claims = explode('.', $response->id_token)[1];
      $claims = json_decode(base64_decode($claims));
    
      echo '<h3>Parsed ID Token</h3>';
      echo '<pre>';
      print_r($claims);
      echo '</pre>';
  
      die();

  }


  function http($url, $params=false) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    if($params)
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
      'Accept: application/json',
      'User-Agent: curl', # Apple requires a user agent header at the token endpoint
    ]);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    return json_decode($response);
  }
```

I've been trying to figure this out the whole day, but literally nothing to be found on the internet, and  I couldn't find any examples about how the user object looks like.

Comment: I'm assuming that `access_token` isn't a real one. Though, I'd probably still go change my API keys.

Comment: @RocketHazmat All the above data is made up.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I cannot read the docs: After successfully authenticating the user, the server returns an identity token, authorization code, and user identifier to your app.

So the solution is:

```
echo "code: " . $_POST["code"] . "<br><br>";
echo "state: " . $_POST["state"] . "<br><br>";
$json = $_POST["user"];
$obj= json_decode($json);
$firstname = $obj->name->firstName;
$lastname = $obj->name->lastName;
$emailaddress = $obj->email;
echo $firstname . '<br>' . $lastname . '<br>' . $emailaddress;
```